# Converting Grid to Geographic?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, xyz

My project specifications are as below:
utilise geodetic and shift parameters between WGS84 and specified datum (ED50), local projection (UTM 31N, CM 3 East) and transformation (EPSG1613) for all positioning requirements....

I am being asked to convert some supplied grid coordinates into LAT / LONG. 
Using some internet software I input the EASTINGS & NORTHINGS and confirm the projection as UTM Zone 31N(ED50), when transferring to geographic should my datum remain ED50 or do i need to use WGS84?